# Excel - read data from ODBCbut paste values only

Tags: excel, odbc, hana

i have an excel document with conditional formatting and data validation lists and lookups.

The users populate this data in Excel.

I then read it into HANA DB and find any new records required to be enriched.

I would like then to be able to refresh the data in Excel with the data i have in HANA however when I go to import via ODBC I then get a table created.

Ideally, it would paste values back into Excel rather than creating a table object as this removed the formatting included originally

Are there ways around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden sheet where you can place your ODBC source table and write a VBA code that will copy and paste new records from ODBC connection to your user-friendly list. You may filter this enriched records via VBA or PowerQuery join or with something like index and match functions.